# como fazer uma busca dos grupos que o usuário participa no Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tenho um app android java e quero saber como faço uma busca dos grupos que um usuário participa...

[image: minha estrutura no Firebase]

como faço o join para buscar apenas os grupos que o usuário participa (a tabela attendee faz a ligação das tabelas group e user)?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser saber quais são os grupos onde o usuário `Z1FZPBz9m0T1yg21DBfRgI2bGFO2` participa, você pode fazer:

```
Query query = db.child("attendee").orderByChild("userUID").equalTo("Z1FZPBz9m0T1yg21DBfRgI2bGFO2");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        for (snap : datasnapshot) {
            String groupUID = snap.getKey();
            // Utilizar o groupID
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

**Actualização:** Para aceder ao objeto grupo:

```
Query query = db.child("attendee").orderByChild("userUID").equalTo("Z1FZPBz9m0T1yg21DBfRgI2bGFO2");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        for (snap : datasnapshot) {
            String groupUID = snap.getKey();
            // Utilizar o groupID para achar o objeto grupo
            db.child("group").child(groupUID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnap) {
                    Group group = dataSnap.getValue(Group.class)
                    //Adicionar o group à lista
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: nesse caso esse código me retornaria a chave do grupo, certo? E se eu precisar retornar o objeto Grupo? para cada grupo que o usuário faz parte... pq o que preciso é ir adicionando à uma lista cada objeto Grupo referente ao grupo que o usuário participa

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta para mostrar como aceder cada objeto grupo

Comment: Se na minha tabela "attendee", no lugar de "userUID" eu tivesse uma lista de "userUID". Como ficaria a query para buscar os grupos que usuário faz parte...?